# Notify fragments in viewpager when async https request finished

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

I have an AppUtils class which handles my network requests. In my activitys onCreate i call the function that initializes a singleton from xml. All it does is make async https post request with okhttps3's enqueue to a server and deserialize the XML response to pojo(singleton).

```
 public static void initSingleton(String apikey)
```

The activity also has a viewpager with 3 different fragments, the fragments all have different views and the goal is to populate the views with the data from the singleton.

What is the best way to notify the fragments when the initSingleton is done doing its work so i can update the views accordingly?

If i simply do Singleton.getInstance().getWhatever() to get a certain value in the fragments onCreateView, the Singleton is obviously not initialized yet, so it gives me a nullpointerexception.

I tried passing a Handler to the function and send a message when the request is finished. It works but i'm only able to notify the activity and not the fragments.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Cheers

**edit:** Is there a more elegant solution than doing it via. handler and then updating the fragment with an interface? Maybe EventBus/Otto?

**edit2:** Ended up realizing it with EventBus, surprisingly easy and the library is pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

Otto/Eventbus can do the stuff for you. 
Localbroadcast manager is also one of the option, no need of any new library dependency in this case.